# Unable to run az pipeline commands within Azure DevOps Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli2

Trying to dynamically retrieve all the variables from a variable group via Azure DevOps task in a YAML Pipeline. Originally tried leveraging the AzureCLI@2 task with the following code to retrieve the variableGroupID which would be used to get the variables inside of it:

```
$variableGroupId = $(az pipelines variable-group list --org $(System.CollectionUri) --project $(System.TeamProject) --query "[?name=='{{ parameters.variableGroupName }}'].id" -o tsv)
```

This command works locally but not when executing on a MS hosted agent like this:

```
parameters:
  variableGroupName: ''

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az upgrade
      $variableGroupId = $(az pipelines variable-group list --org $(System.CollectionUri) --project $(System.TeamProject) --query "[?name=='{{ parameters.variableGroupName }}'].id" -o tsv)
      write-Host $variableGroupId
      $variables = $(az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id $variableGroupId  --org $(System.CollectionUri)  --project $(System.TeamProject) -o yaml)
      write-Host $variables
```

This fails with the error:

```
Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command (az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials. Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information
```

I have opened up an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/2935)

In the meantime, I tried to run the [commands to install the necessary pieces via scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops)

```
   strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: Example - Dev
              WebAppName: wapp-Example-dev-eus
              Package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Web.Example.zip
              TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.x'
              architecture: 'x64'
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Upgrade pip'
            inputs:
              script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'upgrade azure cli'
            inputs:
              script: pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Show Azure CLI version'
            inputs:
              script: az --version
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Install Azure DevOps Extension'
            inputs:
              script: az extension add -n azure-devops
          - task: CmdLine@2
            env:
              AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT: $(patCredential)
            displayName: 'Login Azure DevOps Extension'
            inputs:
              script: echo ${AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT} | az devops login
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Show List of Variables'
            inputs:
              script: |
                $variableGroupId = $(az pipelines variable-group list --org $(System.CollectionUri) --project $(System.TeamProject) --query "[?name=='{{ parameters.variableGroupName }}'].id" -o tsv)
                write-Host $variableGroupId
                $variables = $(az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id $variableGroupId  --org $(System.CollectionUri)  --project $(System.TeamProject) -o yaml)
                write-Host $variables
```

However, when using both latest Ubuntu agents and those designated in the doc get an error:

```
WARNING: Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
WARNING: You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
WARNING: Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.
```

I have opened up an [issue with the documentation team](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10070) as at the very least the provided steps do not work. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Agree with @wallezzi, and we suggest that you [deploy self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), which give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. And use the self-hosted agent in pipeline will build on your local build environment.

Comment: Not sure about that one, I shouldn't have to run a self hosted agent to run native azure cli commands and extensions. Plus self hosted agents is not a possibility

Comment: It seems that you have found the workaround for this issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1337250/view.html, it will be better if you share your workaround here in stackoverflow and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which will help other community members who get the same issues, thanks a lot.

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT Please note the comments that were already posted below. This workaround was first identified here on stackoverflow and the community ticket updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the REST API instead of Azure CLI to get the information. It can be used with the standard tools already present on the Microsoft Hosted agents. It requires only vanilla powershell or powershell core, meaning to works on both windows and linux agents. The below example was successfully tested on `windows-latest`/[`windows-2019`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) and `ubuntu-latest`/[`ubuntu-20.04`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md)

The approach is the same as with Azure CLI.

1. [List all available groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get%20variable%20groups?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) filtered by name to retrieve the variable group in question
2. [Get all variables in the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)  using the variable group id from step

In fact, the pipeline also has an out of the box PAT token available with read access to variable groups. It is stored in the variable [`System.AccessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken). Using that instead of a manually managed one will further simplify things.

The script below is executed in a `pwsh` step, which is the [built in Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) in Powershell core mode

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    # Construct PAT authentication header
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "user",$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)))
    $headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    
    # Retrieve variable group id. Filter the result by setting the groupName query parameter
    $variableGroupId = $(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupName=${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}&api-version=6.0-preview.2").value[0].id
    
    # Retrieve variables in variable group with id $variableGroupId
    $variables = $(Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/${variableGroupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.2").variables
    
    #Print variables as json (for demo purpose)
    $variables | ConvertTo-Json
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'Retrieve variables'
```

Testing the above pipeline in a project on a variable group with two variables yields the following output:

```json
{
  "Variable 1": {
    "value":  "Value 1"
  },
  "Variable 2": {
    "value":  "Value 2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that!! I will try this and get back to you. I did use the system provided one but that resulted in the keychain failure as well.

Comment: I wish this would work with ubuntu.  That being said I did get it to work but needed to make adjustments to the provided answer.  The `{{ parameters.variableGroupName }}` does not read the YAML value.  I ended up being able to change this from a parameter to a variable in the job calling the task template and then doing `groupName=$env:variableGroupName`

Comment: It does work on ubuntu as well (if you use the powershell core version of the task (`pwsh` instead of `powershell`). Updated my answer with that. You could even write a version in bash using something like `curl` and `jq` to call the api and parse the responses if you for some reason prefer that over powershell. But the benefit of using powershell core is that it works on both Linux and windows without modification

Comment: The parameter issue may have been a typo in the reply, should be `
`${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}` rather than `{{ parameters.variableGroupName }}` (it is updated now). It is however hard to give advice around the `variableGroupName` since you have not posted your complete yaml files. But like you say you could use either a parameter or a variable, but they have slightly different syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Comment: I can't believe I missed the `$`!! Apologies for not posting the entire YAML....I didn't as it's been deconstructed via multiple templates so the build Deploy Stage calls a series of deploy jobs which call a series of deploy tasks.  I did update the question to at least show the declaration of the parameter

Comment: No problem, I guess referencing the variable is not part of the core problem anyway. Did you try it out on a Linux agent as well?

Comment: Yeah it did work on Linux thanks. I did update the community ticket as well to reference this workaround. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error, and was able to get mine working by adding:

```
echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login
```

to the top of my inline script. Here's what it looks like:

```
  variables:
    variableGroupName: 'my-variable-group'
    ...

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Set environment variables'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              scriptType: 'pscore'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login

                $groupId = (az pipelines variable-group list `
                --organization $(System.CollectionUri) `
                --project $(System.TeamProject) `
                --group-name $(variableGroupName) | ConvertFrom-Json).id
                
                ...
```